# Obter vários pedaços de uma String igual ao Python

Tags: string, visual-basic-6

Quero fazer uma matriz de primeira dimensão que contém os campos de uma string igual cada bloco da linguagem Python, exemplo:

```
 primeiro bloco é esse
 isso ainda faz
 parte do primeiro bloco
    agora aqui é o segundo
    esse é o segundo bloco também
       agora o terceiro
       aqui é o terceiro
    aqui ainda é o segundo
 primeiro bloco aqui
```

quero que se obtém cada bloco com seus sub-blocos, como por exemplo, no segundo bloco:

```
    agora aqui é o segundo
    esse é o segundo bloco também
       agora o terceiro
       aqui é o terceiro
    aqui ainda é o segundo
```

e no terceiro:

```
    agora o terceiro
    aqui é o terceiro
```

diferenciando cada trecho por um parágrafo de 3 espaços... Será possível fazer isso em .NET? Obrigado!

> Aceito respostas em **Visual Basic .NET e/ou C#** *(Prefiro VB)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bote o texto aqui e ira retornar uma lista com os "pedaços", não há limite de pedaços ou quantidade de sub blocos.

```
    '    Texto'
    Dim textoo As String = 'texto aki'
    '    Separador'
    Const separador As String = "   "


    Dim separadorC As Int16 = separador.Length
    Dim final As New List(Of String)
    final.Add(textoo)
    Dim a
    a = Split(textoo, Chr(10))
    While 0 = 0
        Dim bufferN As New List(Of String)
        For Each b As String In a
            If b.StartsWith(separador) Then
                bufferN.Add(Mid(b, separadorC))
            End If
        Next
        If bufferN.Count = 0 Then
            Exit While
        End If
        Dim bufferF As String = ""
        For Each bufferR As String In bufferN
            bufferF = bufferF & bufferR & Chr(13)
        Next
        final.Add(bufferF)
        a = bufferN
    End While
```

Para ver o resultado, pode se usar:

```
    For Each fim As String In final
        MsgBox(fim)
    Next
```